# Jquery - Select by tag where i want use effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one div where i use **class** and **id**, but i need create some effects over the div and by this need use other tag for apply this changes, actually i want use the tag called **"rel"** howewer i can use other name for this tag .....

I want apply effect by the name of this differente tag and his value

**I try this but no get results**

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".header_col_buttons_color_2").mouseover(function() {

jQuery("id[rel$='2']").css("border","5px solid red")

});


});

</script>


<div id="header_cols" class="header_cols_lateral_barra" rel="2"></div>
```

How i show in the code , the div has one tag called rel="2" and i want put the effect over this tag

Thank´s for help and support , regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such as:

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery(".header_col_buttons_color_2").mouseover(function() {

            jQuery("div[rel='2']").css("border","5px solid red");

        });

    });

</script>

<div id="header_cols" class="header_cols_lateral_barra" rel="2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("div[rel='2']").css("border","5px solid red");
```

Will select the `DIV` where the `rel` attribute has a value of `2`.

Comment: I know - we posted it at the same time. No need for the downvote.